# Does interchangeable wavelength LED exist in NIR?

Tags: wavelength, light-emitting-diodes, infrared-radiation

Does exist a led material that allows to interchange the emitted wavelength in near IR spectrum?

Answer (score 2):

You can't (significantly) change the wavelength of an LED, the color of the light emitted is set by the band gap which depends on the material and doping.

(You can shift it slightly with temperature and overdriving the voltage)

Adjustable color LEDs generally have 3 (or more) Red, Green, Blue diodes in a single case and you vary the power on each to produce an average color.

I haven't seen devices with a variety of IR LEDs in them but it would be easy to make one. At least out to the regions of infrared that Silicon LEDs work in, say 700-950nm?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The LED i'm talking about is GaAIa equiped. Do you know how the temperature and the WL emitted are related?

Comment: If someone could recommend on light source in Near-IR. A substitute of high power leds.

Comment: @Raphael - a regular light bulb is pretty good in Photons/$